# How do I get formatted responses from terminal?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I'm struggling to understand the response that I receive from the terminal as it is all pasted in one line without indentation, line breaks, etc. Is there a way to enable that? Or some command? This is my first time working with Ubuntu, so I apologize in advance if I'm unclear or vague.

**Edit:**

I'm trying out Twilio's API and I sent a GET request to see all the messages sent to a number. I got a response in JSON format. The response is basically lacking line breaks and indentation and other such formatting. Is there a way to somehow make the response appear properly formatted?

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean with "responses from terminal"? Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly are you doing? What output/result/behavior do you get? What would you expect instead?

Comment: so i'm trying out twilio's api and i requested messages sent to a number. i got a response in json format, but the response is basically lacking line breaks and indentation and other such formatting. is there a way to somehow make the response appear properly formatted? i tried looking for it and didn't find anything so i doubt it but i wanted to ask anyway. does that help?

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to provide requested information or clarification.** Don't use comments for this purpose. Whenever possible copy&paste the exact command you use and the corresponding output instead of describing it. Do I understand correct, that tha question is how to format JSON data?

Comment: Or, use `jq`. Read `man jq`. It parses the json for you.

Comment: ... it's probably worth trying simply piping the output through the simplest jq filter `jq '.'` since jq "pretty-prints" its output by default

Comment: ah i see thanks for your help!